# I am trying to wirelessly communicate between to Arduinos using nrf24l01 module

Tags: module, arduino

I am able to get a message out from one to the next, rather my serial monitor does receive data, but not in the correct format.

I am new to the module and am not too sure why this is happening.

Transmit:

```
#include <SPI.h>  
#include "RF24.h"

RF24 myRadio (7, 8);
byte addresses[][6] = {"0"};

struct package
{
  int id=1;
  float temperature = 18.3;
  char  text[100] = "Text to be transmitted"; 
};


typedef struct package Package;
Package data;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  myRadio.begin();  
  myRadio.setChannel(115); 
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  myRadio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS ) ; 
  myRadio.openWritingPipe( addresses[0]);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
  myRadio.write(&data, sizeof(data)); 

  Serial.print("\nPackage:");
  Serial.print(data.id);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println(data.temperature);
  Serial.println(data.text);
  data.id = data.id + 1;
  data.temperature = data.temperature+0.1;
  delay(1000);

}
```

Recieve:

```
#include <SPI.h>  
#include "RF24.h" 

RF24 myRadio (7, 8); 
struct package
{
  int id=0;
  float temperature = 0.0;
  char  text[100] ="empty";
};

byte addresses[][6] = {"0"}; 



typedef struct package Package;
Package data;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  myRadio.begin(); 
  myRadio.setChannel(115); 
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  myRadio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS ) ; 
  myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);
  myRadio.startListening();
}


void loop()  
{

  if ( myRadio.available()) 
  {
    while (myRadio.available())
    {
      myRadio.read( &data, sizeof(data) );
    }
    Serial.print("\nPackage:");
    Serial.print(data.id);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.println(data.temperature);
    Serial.println(data.text);
  }

}
```

This is sample code, I have tried "Hello World" samples as well, I know I am wired correctly. Please help. THank you!

Comment: Have you tried removing `while (myRadio.available())`, What is your output on the receiver?

Comment: I have not tried removing that, no. But the output is gibberish, a bunch of symbols like "????!#%?????@?????" along with some Chinese characters.

Comment: Try these things:
1. Remove `while (myRadio.available())` as it is unnecessary since you have a loop.
2. Add `radio.setAutoAck(1);` and `radio.setRetries(2,15);` before `myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);`
3. Instead of sending a complex struct send a simple int value `unsigned int data`.
These will help you better understand what is the cause of the problem.

Comment: For 3) what would you suggest? Sending a string? A set of numbers?

Comment: As I said just send an int number. With this, you can simply verify what is wrong.
One more tip. put a 10 seconds delay (`delay(10000)`) after last print statement inside your loops to verify that when garbage data ends.
Also, No need to print inside your transmit code, remove them for simplicity.